# Google Cloud Speech API. Help getting Google's own example to work

Tags: google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

Trying to get hints to work with Google Cloud Speech API. However, I can not get Google's own example to work for me. I get the same result with and without hints. I believe the following code is what the documentation is recommending:

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import base64
import googleapiclient.discovery

speech_file = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources',
    'shwazil_hoful.flac')
with open(speech_file, 'rb') as speech:
    b64speech = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(speech.read())

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('speech', 'v1')
service_request = service.speech().recognize(
    body={
        "config": {
            "encoding": "FLAC",  # raw 16-bit signed LE samples
            "sampleRateHertz": 16000,  # 16 khz
            "languageCode": "en-US",  # a BCP-47 language tag
            "speechContexts": [{
                "phrases": ["hoful","shwazil"]
                }]
        },
        "audio": {
            "content": b64speech
            #"uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"
        }
    })

response = service_request.execute()
recognized_text = 'Transcribed Text: \n'
for i in range(len(response['results'])):
    recognized_text += response['results'][i]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']

print(recognized_text)
```

Output:

it's a swazzle **Hopple** day

I was expecting:

it's a swazzle **hoful** day

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

I've tried both Python2 and Python3